# Convert LinqToXml expression to XPath

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I have this linq expression that I need to convert to XPath select element:

```
XElement transIdElement = (from criteria in searchCriteria.Descendants("CRITERIA") 
                           where criteria.Element("DataPointName).Value == "TransactionNumber" 
                           select criteria.Element("CriteriaComparisonValue")).FirstOrDefault();
```

and I tried with this:

```
var transIdElement = searchCriteria.XPathSelectElement("//CRITERIA/DataPointName[text() = 'TransactionNumber']/CriteriaComparisonValue");
```

but I get null as result.

XML sample is:

```
<SEARCH>
    <ADVANCED_CRITERIA>
        <CRITERIA>
            <DataPointName>TransactionNumber</DataPointName>
            <CriteriaComparisonValue>12457845</CriteriaComparisonValue>
        </CRITERIA>
     </ADVANCED_CRITERIA>
</SEARCH>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    string xml = @"<SEARCH>
    <ADVANCED_CRITERIA>
        <CRITERIA>
            <DataPointName>TransactionNumber</DataPointName>
            <CriteriaComparisonValue>12457845</CriteriaComparisonValue>
        </CRITERIA>
     </ADVANCED_CRITERIA>
</SEARCH>";
    var searchCriteria = XElement.Parse(xml);
   searchCriteria.XPathSelectElements("//CRITERIA[DataPointName='TransactionNumber']/CriteriaComparisonValue").Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `..` to access `parent::node()` and try

`//CRITERIA/DataPointName[text() = 'TransactionNumber']/../CriteriaComparisonValue`

quick test in LINQpad:

```
var f = @"c:\temp\x\a.xml";
var searchCrit = XDocument.Load(f);
searchCrit.XPathSelectElement("//CRITERIA/DataPointName[text() = 'TransactionNumber']/../CriteriaComparisonValue").Value.Dump();
```

produces

```
12457845
```

Answer (score 1):

A more accurate XPath translation of your LINQ-to-XML query would be as follow :

```
//CRITERIA[DataPointName = 'TransactionNumber']/CriteriaComparisonValue
```

Here is a glimpse of how the above predicate expression (expression in square brackets) works.

`DataPointName` references child element named `"DataPointName"` of the context element. In this particular predicate, the context element is `CRITERIA`.

`'TransactionNumber'` with quotes surround means literal-string in XPath. When an element compared to a string in XPath, the element is translated into string by calling XPath `string()` function.